# Idiomatic way to handle a stream end with RxJS

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

I need to do a some action when stream ends. What the idiomatic way to do that?

Now I use the code bellow:

```
source.subscribe(undefined, undefined, function() {
  socket.send({type: 'end'});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

1. Use the operator `subscribeOnCompleted()` instead of passing in empty values to the `.subscribe` method.
2. Use `tapOnCompleted()`, same as above, but it won't start the sequence and you can inject it part way through the sequence.
3. Use the `.finally()` which will get executed when the sequence finishes (normally or otherwise).
4. In your example you are showing a side effect but if you were doing clean up of resources it would be more semantic to use `.using()` which takes a disposable and ties it to the lifetime of the subscription.

In order these look like:

1. `source.subscribeOnCompleted(() => socket.send({type: 'end'}));`
2. `source.tapOnCompleted(() => socket.send({type: 'end'})).subscribe()`
3. `source.finally(() => socket.send({type: 'end'})).subscribe()`
4. `Rx.Observable.using(() => createResource(), (resource) => source).subscribe()`

Comment: I guess in my case `tapOnCompleted` is  the best approach